# "The multi-part identifier "V_Products.Now" could not be bound" on an update query

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `t1` and `t2`, which are identical in design. `t1` is the master. `t2` comprises of certain rows from `t1`.

Both are within the same server and both tables have a column called `Now`.

I want to look at both `Now` columns and set `t2` to match whatever `t1` is for that result, or all results (all would be better tbh).

So `t1` is the master and certain rows of `t1` are occasionally moved to `t2`. Occasionally the data in `t1.Now` column gets updated, meaning that `t2` is now out of date.

I have tried the following code:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T2.NOW = T1.Now
WHERE T2.Barcode = T1.Barcode;
```

This gives me the "The multi-part identifier "V_Products.Now" could not be bound" error and Im not sure why.

I might add that I am fairly new to SQL.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Syntax often varies by dbms, and sometimes by version too, so always include that information in any sql questions. You can use the [edit] link to specify your dbms.

Answer (score 1):

You want to update t1 and you write t2 = t1. You should write something like that (works for Postgresql).

```
UPDATE T1 SET NOW = T2.Now
from t2
WHERE T2.Barcode = T1.Barcode;
```

Comment: FYI, you're missing T1 in the FROM clause.  Also exact Syntax depends on the dbms (which unfortunately, they didn't specify)

Comment: This is why i didn't add t1 in from clause. For eg in Postgresql you don't need it...

Comment: It is needed with others like SQL Server, so you might want to add a note it's a Postgresql example :)

Comment: You're right, modification done ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```
UPDATE T1

SET T1.NOW = T2.Now

FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID;
```

Comment: This seems to be almost identical to the answer by Phillipe from yesterday. What's the difference? Can you explain what is the difference between these two solutions?